# Deploying Web application onto AWS from a Git repository

Tags: java, git, amazon-web-services, tomcat, bitbucket

I worked with OpenShift and was able to deploy the Java Tomcat web application from a git (bitbucket) repository URL. Another good option was using rhc.

I am new in AWS and need to deploy the Tomcat Web application onto AWS. I cannot find neither the option to upload from a git repository (bitbucket) nor the a shell command interface.  Are there any options?
I received some answers that it is possible both from AWS Elastic Beanstalk GUI and from eb.  However, I cannot find how to do this, so it would be nice to get the answer in details.  How to get to the screen asking the GIT URL?  What is the eb command?

Comment: Can you describe your environment a bit more?  Are you deploying to an EC2 server directly?  Are you deploying a WAR file?  Are you building the WAR locally and storing it in bitbucket or do you want to build the WAR on the remote system?  With a bit more info I think we can get this working! :D

Comment: Ideally, I would like to do this as I did on OpenShift - give my git URL and get the working application based on the pom.xml in  the repository. The pom. xml should build the war file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you were using OpenShift v2 and now you want to migrate to AWS. The AWS [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) service is a PaaS that should be very similar to what you are used to using with OpenShift v2. Elastic Beanstalk has an `eb` command that is similar to the `rhc` command, and Elastic Beanstalk can trigger deployments from Git, very similar to how OpenShift v2 deployments worked.

Comment: Added some comments, can you please look?